# ClassGraph, how to filter the classpath's content

Tags: java, classpath

I try to find an answer to the following question. If somebody has a hint, i would appreciate.

I try to find the runtime classpath using ClassGraph:

```
String classpath = new ClassGraph().getClasspath();
```

The classpath content looks as follows:

```
C:\work\WildFlyAppServer\WildFlyAppServer14\jre\windows64\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;
C:\work\WildFlyAppServer\WildFlyAppServer14\jre\windows64\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;
C:\work\WildFlyAppServer\WildFlyAppServer14\jre\windows64\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;
C:\work\WildFlyAppServer\WildFlyAppServer14\jre\windows64\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;
C:\work\WildFlyAppServer\WildFlyAppServer14\jre\windows64\lib\ext\localedata.jar;
C:\work\WildFlyAppServer\WildFlyAppServer14\jre\windows64\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;
...

C:\work\dev\MyWebApplication\myapp\exploded-jb7\myapp.ear\myapp.war\WEB-INF\lib\myjar1.jar;
C:\work\dev\MyWebApplication\myapp\exploded-jb7\myapp.ear\myapp.war\WEB-INF\lib\myjar2.jar;
C:\work\dev\MyWebApplication\myapp\exploded-jb7\myapp.ear\myapp.war\WEB-INF\lib\myjar3.jar;
C:\work\dev\MyWebApplication\myapp\exploded-jb7\myapp.ear\myapp.war\WEB-INF\lib\myjar4.jar;
...

C:\work\WildFlyAppServer\WildFlyAppServer14\server\myapp\tmp\vfs\deployment\deployment82593206c83a71cc\myjar1.jar-a43b90541d67f63b\myjar1.jar;
C:\work\WildFlyAppServer\WildFlyAppServer14\server\myapp\tmp\vfs\deployment\deployment82593206c83a71cc\myjar2.jar-fc9118a07f840a67\myjar2.jar;
.....

C:\work\WildFlyAppServer\WildFlyAppServer14\modules\system\layers\base\com\sun\xml\bind\main\jaxb-core-2.3.0.jar;
C:\work\WildFlyAppServer\WildFlyAppServer14\modules\system\layers\base\com\sun\xml\bind\main\jaxb-runtime-2.3.0.jar;
....
```

I would like to filter, for example, the jars that comes from: C:\work\WildFlyAppServer\WildFlyAppServer14\server\myapp\tmp

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Even though I haven't used ClassGraph, with a quick look at the [documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.github.classgraph/classgraph/4.8.5/io/github/classgraph/ClassGraph.html) I think you should use [this](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.github.classgraph/classgraph/4.8.5/io/github/classgraph/ClassGraph.html#filterClasspathElements(io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.ClasspathElementFilter)) method to create your ClassGraph object and pass an implementation of [this](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.github.classgraph/classgraph/4.8.5/io/github/classgraph/ClassGraph.ClasspathElementFilter.html) functional interface as a parameter.

So basically something along the lines of:

```
ClasspathElementFilter classpathElementFilter = (java.lang.String classpathElementPathStr) -> {
/* here check whether classpathElementPathStr is a path you want to scan. 
If yes return true */ 
}
ClassGraph myClassGraph = filterClasspathElements(classpathElementFilter);
String classpath = myClassGraph.getClasspath();
```

I hope this was helpful.